# Вывод нажатой клавиши JButton в JLabel

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Project2 extends JFrame {
    JLabel lOutput;
    JButton b7, b8, b9, b4, b5, b6, b1, b2, b3, bc, b0,
            bEqually, bDivision, bMultiplication, bAddition, bMinus;
    int i, k;
    String a, b;

    public Project2(String s) {
        super(s);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        lOutput = new JLabel("");
        b7 = new JButton("7");
        b8 = new JButton("8");
        b9 = new JButton("9");
        bDivision = new JButton("/ ");
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        b6 = new JButton("6");
        bMultiplication = new JButton("*");
        b1 = new JButton("1");
        b2 = new JButton("2");
        b3 = new JButton("3");
        bAddition = new JButton("+");
        bc = new JButton("C");
        b0 = new JButton("0");
        bEqually = new JButton("=");
        bMinus = new JButton("-");

        add(lOutput);
        add(b7);
        add(b8);
        add(b9);
        add(bDivision);
        add(b4);
        add(b5);
        add(b6);
        add(bMultiplication);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(bAddition);
        add(bc);
        add(b0);
        add(bEqually);
        add(bMinus);
    }

    public class eHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerforned(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.setSource() == b7;) {
                //??????????????????????????????????????
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: я создаю калькулятор (это моя первая практика, прошу не судите строго), создал несколько кнопок и хотелось бы, чтобы после каждого нажатия на определенную кнопку в `JLabel` все отображалось. Возможно я немного не втюхиваю и `JLabel` нужно заменить на `JTextField`, пожалуйста, укажите и это. И как самому последнему чайнику, я бы попросил, все объяснить подробно и на русском.).

Comment: В методе actionPerformed берите label и вызывает метод setText (label.setText("Some text"));
Если вы просто хотите выводить сообщение о нажатой кнопки , то public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ loutput.setText(e.getSource().getText));

Comment: Почему getText высвечивается ошибкой?